# Repeat n time xml node with xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi all I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<service>
  <metadata>
        <collection>
                <metadata_id>id</metadata_id>
                <metadata_uuid>uuid</metadata_uuid>
        </collection>
  </metadata>
</service>
```

and I would like to repeat n time the node 
`<collection>...</collection>`
to have the following output (id and uuid will always be different within each node)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<service>
  <metadata>
        <collection>
                <metadata_id>id</metadata_id>
                <metadata_uuid>uuid</metadata_uuid>
        </collection>
        <collection>
                <metadata_id>id</metadata_id>
                <metadata_uuid>uuid</metadata_uuid>
        </collection>
        <collection>
                <metadata_id>id</metadata_id>
                <metadata_uuid>uuid</metadata_uuid>
        </collection>
        <collection>
                <metadata_id>id</metadata_id>
                <metadata_uuid>uuid</metadata_uuid>
        </collection>
.... (n time)

  </metadata>
</service>
```

I'm trying to use the identity transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="service">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="metadata"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Select Particular Elements -->   
  <xsl:template match="metadata">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I'm not sure how to repeat the node to get the desired output. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion with a parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="max">4</xsl:param>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="metadata">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="collection">
      <xsl:param name="n" select="1"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="$n &lt; $max">
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
              <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 1"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="collection/*">
      <xsl:param name="n"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', $n)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknt3

Note that in XSLT 2 with (1 to 4) you can directly construct a sequence to process with `xsl:for-each` or in XSLT 3 with `xsl:iterate` or `fold-left`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer Martin it works like a charm